# Select Newly Added Row in Office UI Fabric DetailsList

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I have a DetailsList for which I need to keep track of the current selection. My problem is I need to update my state when the user changes the selection, but also be able to set the selection when a new row is added. If I'm listening to user events via onSelectionChanged, I can't call setSelectionKey because it will just cycle back and forth.

Possibly related is that since I am adding a new row, I can't select it until the render that repopulates the items, but I'm not sure when I would even call setSelectedKey to ensure that's already done.

I have a version that kind of works by setting a flag to call setItems and then setSelectedKey while temporarily telling onSelectionChanged to ignore it, but I believe it's causing extra renders and doesn't work in all situations.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Can you post a codepen that encapsulates what you're doing? May help someone tackle this by working directly with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem was I was just setting the previously selected item to selected, e.g. `selection.setKeySelected(item.id, true)`. The secret turned out to be setting all of the other items to not be selected. Here are the relevant parts:

```
const selection = new Selection({ 
  getKey: item => item.id,
  onSelectionChanged: () => {
    the_chosen_one = selection.getSelection()[0];
    // ... do whatever with the item the user just selected ...
  }
});

...

// In some handler when you need to select/re-select an item:
const onWhatever = () => {
  setChangeEvents(false);
  state.items.forEach(item => {
    selection.setKeySelected(item.id, item.id === the_chosen_one.id);
  });
  setChangeEvents(true);
};

...

<DetailsList selection={selection} items={state.items} ...
```

I'm not sure the setChangeEvents part is necessary, but it didn't hurt. The documentation on this is non-existent so the only way to figure it out is reading the code and browsing through Github issues, but a lot of those turned out to be dead ends. I still don't understand why I have to explicitly de-select items that were never selected in the first place, but that's what it was.

I hope this helps someone else some day.